# Regexp format "YYYY/NNNN" or "YYYY/NNNN/Country code"

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this regexp: `(\d{4})\/(\d{2,4})\/?(\w{2})?` which seems to work properly, but I want to avoid the cases in which for example: I have a string "2020/2000/WEEEE"  and it matches it.

Other wrong example that it matches: "IEN/BSK-2020/143999" .

How can I avoid this and take only the strings with the specified format from above? "YYYY/NNNN" and "YYYY/NNNN/Country code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the first part with the digits and the forward slash, and make the whole last part including the `/` optional asserting a whitspace boundary at the right using `(?!\S)`

```
\b(\d{4})\/(\d{2,4})(?:\/(\w{2}))?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIPEzn/1)

A bit more precise pattern, where the country code can only be chars a-z, and without escaping the forward slash (when it is not the delimiter). If you don't need the 3 capture groups as separate values for processing, you can omit them.

```
\b(\d{4})/(\d{2,4})(?:/([a-zA-Z]{2}))?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jrLHJ3/1)

Comment: 4444/1234/en,2020/1234/EN  in this example with the regexp that you provided it is validating only "2020/1234/EN". Is it possible to take both if the numbers are separated by commas or other punctuation marks/separators?

Comment: @Razvan you could rule out word characters or a forward slash instead for example https://regex101.com/r/z79gQW/1 `\b(\d{4})\/(\d{2,4})(?:\/(\w{2}))?(?![\w/])`